# Show that $a·c \equiv b·c\ (\text{mod }m)$ with $a, b, c$ and $m$ integers with $m \ge 2$ does not imply $a \equiv b\ (\text{mod }m)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Show that $a·c\equiv b·c\ (\text{mod }m)$ with $a, b, c$ and $m$ integers with $m \ge 2$ does not imply $a \equiv b\ (\text{mod }m)$

I've seen many similar examples, but can't seem to find a step by step explanation or solution to any of them (like an actual proof).

Comment: It's no fun unless you require $c\not\equiv 0 \pmod m$.

Answer (score 0):

The *cancellation law* fails in rings that have **zero divisors**:

On one hand, if $ac=bc$ with $a\ne b$ and $c\ne 0$, then $(a-b)c=0$, where both factors are nonzero.

On the other hand, if $xy=0$ but $x$ and $y$ are both zero divisors, then $a=x, b=0, c=y$ will be a counterexample for your task.

So you want to find a pair of zero divisors modulo $m$. The easiest way to do that is for $m$ itself to be a non-trivial product ...

Answer (score 0):

$0\cdot2\equiv2\cdot2 \mod4$ but $0\not\equiv2\mod4$. You need to ask $c$ to be coprime with $m$ in order to cancel it.

Answer (score 0):

To show that $p$ implies $q$ is false, present a situation in which $p$ is true and $q$ is false.  In this case, start by finding $a$, $b$, and $m$ for which $a$ and $b$ are not congruent mod $m$.  Then let $c$ be any multiple of $m$.